# intuition behind basis of a root system

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

I am reading Lie Algebra book by James E.Humphreys. I can understand the fruitfulness of the notion of basis of a root system. But what is the intuition behind this definition, In particular the condition that every root is a integer linear combination of roots in the basis $\Delta$ with **all the coefficients of same sign** by using which we define positive roots.

Thanks in advance.